# смешение стилей

Tags: html, css

у меня есть 2 разные html страницы, и у каждой есть свой css файл. У этих страниц общий header в котором прописаны пути к обоим файлам css
На самих страницах есть див (с одинаковым классом)
и вот вопрос - как сделать чтобы стили не путались, и в зависимости от того на какой странице мы находимся - для поля у которого один и тот же класс подгружались разные стили?

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ - вы не должны хотеть добиться этого результата.

В традиционной верстке с глобальным CSS-ом, названия классов должны быть уникальными для каждого типа блока. Иначе говоря, если какой-нибудь класс `.phone` выглядить на странице index.html так, а на products.html эдак, то тут что-то пошло не так. Такой код будет тяжело поддерживать, вы сами скоро начнете путаться где какой класс, а человек, который будет работать с этим кодом после вас как минимум будет сконфужен. Смотрите в сторону методологий написания стилей, самая популярная и фактически стандарт индустрии - БЭМ. Так у вас будет все тот же глобальный файл стилей, где на странице index.html `.phone` будет выглядеть как нужно для этой страницы, а на странице products.html будет уже какой-нибудь `.phone phone--secondary` - который будет выглядет как-нибудь иначе.